# How can I resize cefsharp devtools when it is minimized?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

When using cefsharp on winforms, after opening devtools, when **minimized**, devtools disappears! It is not in the taskbar. It cannot be opened again. What should I do? Call `browser.ShowDevTools()` again and it will not come out.
How can I resize it?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: cefsharp 67.0.0, net452

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such an old version? This was fixed over two years ago https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/44113d77a47263276bc87f5108f8035f410c16a6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at all possible I'd suggest you upgrade to the current supported version (102 at time of writing), you'll get a huge number of bug fixes and improvements.

In newer versions the `DevTools Window` will appear in the task bar. This behaviour was changed in version `79`, relevant [commit](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/44113d77a47263276bc87f5108f8035f410c16a6).

---

If you are unable to upgrade then you'll need to change how you open `DevTools`.

The following should hopefully work, I've not tested.

```cs
var host = chromiumWebBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost();

var windowInfo = new WindowInfo();
windowInfo.SetAsPopup(null, "DevTools");

host.ShowDevTools(windowInfo);
```

Comment: thank you！i should upgrade newer version